# Powermock - mocking static class members

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, easymock

I'm trying to mock the following class which contains some static members

```
public class ClientFact {

    private static final String BASE_URL = Config.getProperty("prop1");
    private static final String USERID = Config.getProperty("prop2");

    ......................

    public static Client createClient() throws AppException {

    }

}
```

but i'm running into issues with the static member variables which are populated by Config.getProperty. This class does a read on a properties file like so

```
public class Config {

...............

    public static String getProperty(Param param) {
       String value = null;
       if (param != null) {
        value = properties.getProperty(param.toString());
       }
       return value;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to mock this call since i dont care about the loaded properties in my test. This is what ive tried

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClientFact.class})

public class MyTests {


    @Test
    public void test() {

        PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(Config.class, "getProperty");
EasyMock.expect(Config.getProperty(EasyMock.anyObject())).andReturn(EasyMock.anyString()).anyTimes();

    PowerMock.mockStatic(ClientFact.class);

    }


}
```

> but its giving the following error...
>
> ```
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/easymock/internal/MocksControl.createMock(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>   at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.doCreateMock(PowerMock.java:2214)
>   at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.doMock(PowerMock.java:2163)
> ```

any ideas what im doign wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like conflicting dependencies versions, verify your dependencies

Answer (score 1):

A non-answer: consider not making **static** calls there.

You see, that directly couples that one class to the implementation of that static method in some other class; for no real reason. (and for the record: it seems strange that a **USER_ID** String is a *static* field in your ClientFact class. Do you really intend that all ClientFacts are using the same USER_ID?!)

You could replace that static call with a non-static version (for example by introducing an interface); and then you can use **dependency injection** to make an instance of that interface available to your class under test. And then all your testing works **without** the need to Powermock.

Long story short: very often (but not always!) the need to turn to Powermock originates in production code which wasn't written to be testable (like in your case). Thus instead of using the big bad Powermock hammer to "fix" your testing problem, you should consider improving your production code.

You might want to listen to those [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) to get a better understanding what I am talking about.

Comment: thanks for the links... its legacy code :) ... so im stuck with it in the meantime... so with the inteface idea, i'd wrap the Config class in a new implementation and pass to the createClient.... is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. But of course, if you can't (or dont want to) change that code, then yes, Powermock is a viable alternative; and it should be possible to get it to do what you need. In that case, I suggest to do some searching; and looking into examples ;-)